if $\int g\phi =\int f\phi$ for all $\phi \in C^{\infty}_{c}(U)$, then $f=g \quad a.e.$
In Folland's real analysis textbook, on page 283, he mentioned that for an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $f,g \in L_{loc}^{1}(U)$ .$f$ and $g$ define the same distribution precisely when they are equal a.e.

I wonder how do we show this formally, that is if $\int g\phi =\int f\phi$ for all $\phi \in C^{\infty}_{c}(U)$, then $f=g \quad a.e.$

Intuitively, my rough proof idea is to use contradiction and partition of unity, where in order to use a partition of unity, we need some open set containing a compact set structure to build a bump function. But I'm having trouble pinning down the exact detail, maybe something like $f_{n} \to f$ uniformly on some compact set and $g_{n} \to g$ uniformaly on some compact set, and $|f_{n}-g_{n}|>\epsilon$ on some rectangle and then build the bump function of rectangle. However, I'm not certain how to exactly do so.

Here seems to the answer, I voted to close this, but if there are other ways to attack this problem, might be interesting to see as well.

For each interval $I = [a,b]$, you can find a sequence of bump functions $0 \leq \phi_n \leq 1$ such that $\phi_n \to \mathbb{1}_I$. Since
$$\int (f -g) \phi_n = 0$$
for each $\phi_n$, you can use the dominated convergence theorem to deduce that
$$\int (f -g) \mathbb{1}_I = 0,$$
so $f - g = 0$ a.e on $I$.
Since this is true for every interval $I$, it should also hold for every Borel set $J \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. In particular, $f - g = 0$ a.e on the Borel sets $J_1 = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) - g(x) > 0\}$ and $J_2 = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) - g(x) < 0\}$.
It follows that $f = g$ a.e, as needed.

It's not clear to me how $\int_I(f-g) = 0$ implies $f=g $ on $I$.

Suppose first that $f - g$ is nonnegative. Write $A = {x \in {I} : f - g > 0}$ as the union $A = \displaystyle\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty {x \in I : f  - g > 1/n}$. To show that $f - g = 0$ a.e we need to show that $A$ has measure zero. If it does not, then there is some $n$ such that  $A_n = {x \in I : f  - g > 1/n}$ has positive measure. But now $\int (f-g) \geq \int_{A_n} f-g = \frac{m(A_n)}{n} > 0$, which is a contradiction. For general integrable functions $f -g$, apply this argument to the positive and negative parts.

How do you know the positive part integrates to 0?

Let $I =[0,1]$, $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be defined as $f(x) = 2x-1$ and let $g=0$. Then $$\int (f -g) \mathbb{1}I = \int (2x-1) \mathbb{1}{[0,1]}(x) dx = \int_0^1 (2x-1) dx =0,$$
but $f - g = f \neq 0$ a.e on $I$.
